# How to specify a different locale for postgreSQL installation?

Tags: postgresql, locale

My system's locale is en_US.UTF-8. Because of that, the postgreSQL installation uses this locale by default for the cluster during installation.

```
Creating new cluster 9.3/main ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.3/main
  data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
  locale en_US.UTF-8
  port   5432
```

But I want my postgreSQL server to install with locale pt_BR.UTF-8.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found a solution for this problem! Here it is..

## 1- Stop and drop your current cluster:

```
$ sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 9.3 main
```

## 2- Create a new cluster with the correct locale:

```
$ sudo locale-gen pt_BR.UTF-8
$ sudo pg_createcluster --locale pt_BR.UTF-8 9.3 main
```

## 3- Confirm it worked as expected:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
(9.3)
=> show LC_COLLATE;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply install it using below commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

and then change the datastorage location :

```
/etc/postgresql/<VERSION>/main/postgresql.conf
```

eg : vi /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf

Search for "data_directory" and provide your new datapath, now save the file and restart the postgresSQL service to reflect this new change.

Considered : your new path is /Database/Storage

Make sure, datapath is accessible only by postgres user - command to do that.

chown postgres.postgres /Database/Storage
chmod 700 /Database/Storage

Hopes this helps,

Comment: But.. by "locale" in this context I'm referring to en_US.UTF8, pt_BR.UTF8, etc..